# Show a dialog only once (implement a dirty bit system) with GDrive Scripting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dialog that is opened inside the onLoad method of a Google Drive spreadsheet.

It has a version number and my goal would be to show it just once to each user, when the version number is bigger than the stored user version number.

Is there a way to do this? I cannot use cookies and as far as I know I cannot use localstorage. Any ideas?

I need something like this:

```
if(get_user_version_number() < my_version_number){
    set_user_version_number(my_version_number);
    showDialog();
}
```

How can I implement the get and set function easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved like this:

```
function openDialog() {
    var current_version = 1;
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var user_version = userProperties.getProperty('LAST_SHOWN_DIALOG');
    if(user_version == null ||user_version < current_version)
    {
        userProperties.setProperty('LAST_SHOWN_DIALOG', current_version)
        var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('message');
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(html);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read 'storing data' in the docs. There are many options.
Most likely you need to use scriptProperties storage.